# Show form on action

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Many application open up with just the top toolbar visible, once a new project is made or opened the rest of the window gets filled. How is this behavior created? Does it use hidden elements or are there forms within the main form that get loaded?

I am currently building a application that builds various charts from log files. Currently things are a bit messy and I want to have regular windows behavior so others can find there way within my app as things are getting more complicated. Currently my app opens with lots of buttons that do not even function until certain things are loaded/done.

-edit-

I am having a hard time being more clear. What i want is:

- Start application with just the top toolbar.
- Once a project gets loaded the window gets populated. Currently all my stuff like charts and buttons are already there. I want these to appear after a project gets loaded. Like you Photoshop it opens with just the top toolbar, once you open or create a new file it opens up a new "field" inside the main window. What is this field, is it a form or a area that gets unhidden or created and populated when a file is opened

Comment: Those are called MDI applications.

Comment: Multiple document interface, great i have some reading to do. Thank, still some more pointers are welcome.

Comment: When the question gets reopened I will post an answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Reopened :)

Comment: Thanks for reopening, although the comment naming MDI helped me a lot already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called MDI's ([Multiple-Document Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

All you have to do is setting the `IsMdiContainer` on your `Form`.

Then simply create a new form and set the `MdiParent` to the parent form:

```
YourMdiForm yourMdiForm = new YourMdiForm();
yourMdiForm.MdiParent = this;
yourMdiForm.Show();
```

Comment: I have this popup window before i load the parent child. Is there a quick way to call the parent form to set MdiParent or do i have to reference it through my popup form?

Comment: @MennoGouw: the 'parent child'. That is confusing... You set the `MdiParent` from the form where you are instantiating it.

Comment: Errr sorry, i meant parent form. When i press new it loads a separate popup form where the user can type the project name, etc. From within here i open the child of the main window. Currently i pass the main/parent form as a reference to the constructor of the popup form so i can set the correct parent of the child it creates (since i cannot use "this" there). I was wondering if there is a easy method to access the parent since i can imagine this needs to be done a lot of times when not in the parent class, so "this" cannot be used.

Comment: @MennoGouw: I am not sure, but when you open the second dialog using `ShowDialog`, it might be possible that the ParentForm is set on the dialog form. You could use that.

Comment: I imagine that does not count for a form created separate from the MDI interface. It might do for a child window, i'll have a look. I have some more reading/learning to do about this but i'm making steps already. Thanks.

Comment: @MennoGouw: Glad I could help. If not, ask the community, often there is a good solution for this. If not, stay with the manual code.

Comment: Sounds to me as a good job for Ninject or some other IoC. You may have a `IMyMainForm` bound only once to your main MDI form (container) and child ones will get automatically injected through constructor, similar to: `public ChildForm(IMyMainForm mainForm)`. You may also consider the Factory Pattern.